# Update product stock based on store id Magento 2

Tags: product, magento-2.1, multistore, quantity

I have created a multi-store view for my Magento site. In my custom extension I've successfully load store id and product, now I want to update the product quantity for specific store id, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Any solution for this?